# Counting number of entries by ID in R?

Tags: r, count

So I'm trying to count the number of entries by ID in R, I'll use a modified version of mtcars to get my point across.  Here's the data:

```
car type            mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
Mazda RX4           21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
Mazda RX4           21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
Datsun 710          22.8   4 108.0  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
Datsun 710          21.4   6 258.0 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
```

I want to end up with a table that counts the number of entries for each ID, so that my results are:

```
Mazda RX4  2
Datsun 710 2
```

Should be a fairly simple and straightforward solution, but I'm new to R and can't quite figure it out.  Should I use "Aggregate"?

Comment: @akrun Add your comment as an answer, it solves the issue ;)

Comment: identical column names are allowed in R? I think to remember not, your example is almost useless anyway.

Comment: @SabDeM I think the OP might have converted the `mtcars` to `matrix`

Comment: Or more generically using dplyr on a data frame named df with an ID variable named id, `tally(group_by(df, id))`.

Comment: So yeah, I had converted it to matrix, but I edited the original post to better get at my question.  The carnames are not row names, they're actually just a column in and of themselves.  So basically I want to tally the number of appearances of each type of car in that column.  Sorry for the confusioN!

Comment: Yes but why the minus votes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using dplyr on a data frame named df with an ID variable called id:

```
library(dplyr)
tally(group_by(df, id))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use either `table` or `count`

```
  as.data.frame(table(rownames(mtcars)))
```

Or

```
  library(plyr)
  count(rownames(mtcars))
```

If you need the count for one of the column,

```
  as.data.frame(table(yourdf$id))
```